# Matching land parcel polygon corners to corners on World Imagery basemap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.

I have a land parcel/cadastre layer of polygons which do not match up with the street corners on the World Imagery satellite basemap of ArcGIS.

Land Parcel layer is using, WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere.

How do I get the Land Parcel corners to line up with the World Imagery basemap street corners?

Comment: Did your Land Parcel data come with that coordinate system?  If so, where did it come from?  If not, then how did it get it?  How far from being lined up is it?

Comment: Yes, Land Parcel data came with that coord system. I'm accessing a database at my work so that's where it came from. No clue as to where the database info comes from. The land parcel corners are about 40m off from the satellite image corners.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.